# Spacing between checkboxes and values

Tags: html, css

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8to42fz8/)

How would I go about editing the HTML/CSS  to create spacing between each checkbox/value pairing? Right now each checkbox and each value are spaced evenly. I'd like value1 to be close to checkbox1, but checkbox2 to have some distance from the value1.

Code here:

```
.checkboxes {
  text-align:center;
}

.checkboxes input{
  margin: 0 20px 0;
}

<div class="checkboxes">
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="One" value="One"> One
    <input type="checkbox" name="Two" value="Two"> Two
    <input type="checkbox" name="Three" value="Three"> Three
    <input type="checkbox" name="Four" value="Four"> Four
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at https://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/BiHzp - you can not style the attributes of elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use This Code

```css
.checkboxes {
  text-align:center;
}

.checkboxes input{
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.checkboxes label{
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 3px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>

  <body>
    <div class="checkboxes">
    <span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Mow" value="Mow"> <label>One</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Weedeat" value="Weedeat"> <label>Two</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Edge" value="Edge"> <label>Three</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Other" value="Other"> <label>Four</label>
    </span>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to reduce right margin a bit and may need to increase left margin

```
.checkboxes input{
  margin: 0 5px 0 30px;
}
```

```css
.checkboxes {
  text-align:center;
}

.checkboxes input{
  margin: 0 5px 0 30px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="checkboxes">
      <span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Mow" value="Mow"> One
        <input type="checkbox" name="Weedeat" value="Weedeat"> Two
        <input type="checkbox" name="Edge" value="Edge"> Three
        <input type="checkbox" name="Other" value="Other"> Four
      </span>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS in this way `margin: top left bottom right;`

```
.checkboxes input{
  margin: 0 5px 0 20px;
}
```

```css
.checkboxes {
  text-align:center;
}

.checkboxes input{
  margin: 0 5px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxes">
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="One" value="One"> One
    <input type="checkbox" name="Two" value="Two"> Two
    <input type="checkbox" name="Three" value="Three"> Three
    <input type="checkbox" name="Four" value="Four"> Four
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a ID to checkbox one and write a style for that separately,
[JSFiddle Code Here](https://jsfiddle.net/8to42fz8/1/)

```
   #chk1 {
      margin :0px !important;
    }

    <div class="checkboxes">
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="Mow" value="Mow"> One
    <input type="checkbox" name="Weedeat" value="Weedeat"> Two
    <input type="checkbox" name="Edge" value="Edge"> Three
    <input type="checkbox" name="Other" value="Other"> Four
  </span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently declaring three values for the input's margin.

Declare four so you can target top, left, bottom, and right, respectively.

```css
.checkboxes {
  text-align: center;
}

.checkboxes input{
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxes">
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="One" value="One"> One
    <input type="checkbox" name="Two" value="Two"> Two
    <input type="checkbox" name="Three" value="Three"> Three
    <input type="checkbox" name="Four" value="Four"> Four
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you added padding on both side of checkbox

```
 /*margin: 0 20px;*/
  margin-left: 40px;
```

```css
.checkboxes {
  text-align:center;
}

.checkboxes input{
  /*margin: 0 20px;*/
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxes">
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="One" value="One"> One
    <input type="checkbox" name="Two" value="Two"> Two
    <input type="checkbox" name="Three" value="Three"> Three
    <input type="checkbox" name="Four" value="Four"> Four
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap each input and its text in its own element and give them spacing of some kind:

```
<div class="checkboxes">
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="One" value="One">
    One    
  </span>
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Two" value="Two">
    Two
  </span>
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Three" value="Three">
    Three
  </span>
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Four" value="Four">
    Four
  </span>
</div>
```

```
.checkboxes {
  padding: 10px;
}

span {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8to42fz8/5/

---

Also, what you want to use for text describing inputs is `label`, but plain text is just as well here.